# Multiple Reports in one SQL Statement

Tags: oracle

I have to generate 200+ **separate** extractions using (Oracle) SQL. The queries are identical with the exception of a where condition.  I am not allowed to define the list in java and reference that.

Using only SQL, is there a way I can automate the process.

This is a flow I can imagine:

1. Define the array to store the different search conditions
2. While the array is not exhausted

   2.1 Execute the SQL for that array subscript into a file having that search condition in the name (to avoid overwriting the file)

Thank you

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.. It looks like a pure coding assistance question

Comment: Are you looking for something like `where (itemno = :itemno or :itemno is null) and (productgroup like :prodgrppattern or :prodgrppattern is null) ...`?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including: DDL statements for your tables; DML statements for your example data; examples of the queries you want to generate; your expected output; and **your** attempted solution and a description of where it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script:

SQL script to generate you the select statements and spools. The scripts generates the statements and then runs them in separate spools

```
    set serveroutput on size 1000000
    set verify off
    set feedback off
    spool script.sql

    declare
      v_main_select varchar2(32000):= 'select col1, col2, col3 from table1'; -- your main statement
    begin
      for r_query in (select condition, where_statement from (
                            select 'condition1' condition, 'where id = 10' where_statement from dual -- your condition name and where statements
                            union 
                            select 'condition2', 'where id = 11' from dual
                            -- more unions for each condition....
                            )
                      ) loop
        dbms_output.put_line('spool'||' '||r_query.condition);
        dbms_output.put_line(v_main_select||' '||r_query.where_statement||';');
        dbms_output.put_line('spool off');
      end loop;
    end;
    /

    spool off

    @script.sql
```